# flutter build apk causing error: Keystore file not found for signing config 'release'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to build a flutter app for release and I following the steps provided here: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android . But whenever I am trying to build it I am getting the following error:

```
Keystore file 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\flutter_quiz_final\android\app\C:Program FilesAndroidAndroid Studiojrebinkey.jks' not
 found for signing config 'release'.
```

Following is my key.properties file:

```
storePassword=******
keyPassword=*****
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\key.jks
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this error, please?

Comment: Keep the **.jks** file in the project folder then define the path or set the correct path and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the file path with a double slash(//)

```
C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\GitHub\\flutter_quiz_final\\android\\app\\C:Program FilesAndroidAndroid Studiojrebinkey.jks
```

And also better to put your .jks file to android directory.